# PHP Create Multidimensional Array with Reduce

Tags: php

I am trying to make an array of arrays. Each array ($group) in the array ($multi_array) needs to be at most 40 items.

```
$multi_array = array_reduce($items, function($acc, $item) {

  if (count($acc) % 40 === 0) {
    array_push($acc, [$item]);
  } else {
    array_push($acc[count($acc) - 1], $item);
  }

  return $acc;
}, []);

var_dump(count($multi_array));

foreach ($multi_array as $group) {
  var_dump(count($group));
}
```

However in the first var_dump(count($multi_array)); the value is 1. In the next var_dump the value is 546. I am expecting $rate_limit_array to have at least 13 arrays of length 40. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong inside my reduce function? To achieve my goal, should I take a different approach in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a different way to do this with [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$multi_array = array_chunk($items, 40, true);
```